# Why does curl_errno() return 0 when there was errors in combination with curl_multi_init()?

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, http-status-codes, curl-multi

I have a list of domains which i want to check if they are active or not. I can check each one separately but I'm having hard time getting the batch to work.

```
  $c200= array();
  $c301= array();
  $c302= array();

$urls=array();
  foreach (new SplFileObject("oList.txt") as $line) {
    $urls[]=$line;

}
//print_r($urls);

$mh = curl_multi_init();
foreach ($urls as $key => $value) {
  $ch[$key] =curl_init($value);
  curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$key]);

}

do{
  curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  curl_multi_select($mh);
}while ($running > 0);

foreach (array_keys($ch) as $key) {

  echo curl_getinfo($ch[$key], CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  echo "\n";

  curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch[$key]);
}
curl_multi_close($mh)
```

I wrote the above code but it gives me zeros as output. 
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### `curl_errno()` does not return the resulting code if it's used inside `curl_multi`.

It seems it is undocumented but if an error occures inside a `curl_multi()` then the `resources` will not have resulting error-code until `curl_multi_info_read()` is called. There is a referencing bug/documentation request: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79318&thanks=4

#### Original answer

Usually when I interfere with a `0` as response code then I have a local issue (dns, network, ssl, url..).

In order to dig further you can check if curl had an error with the execution. This can be checked by [curl_errno()](https://www.php.net/curl_errno) which returns an curl error number and [curl_error()](https://www.php.net/curl_error) which will return an descriptive error string.

The error-code and error-message will be perhaps one of those you can find here: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html

**EDIT #2**

If you work with curl_multi you need to call `curl_multi_info_read()` once to get the resulting codes. Below is an example how you can fetch the relevant result entry.

```
// your code...

do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    curl_multi_select($mh);
} while ($running > 0);

while ($result = curl_multi_info_read($mh)) {
    if ($result['result'] == CURLM_OK) {
        echo 'Success: ' . curl_getinfo($result['handle'], CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) . "\n";
    } else {
        echo 'Error: ' . curl_strerror($result['result']) . "\n";
    }
}
```

A real test will now result the following:

```
$ php test.php 
Error: Couldn't resolve host name
Success: 200
Success: 200
```

**EDIT #3**

Additionally it seems that calling `curl_multi_info_read($mh)` does the trick as well and populates internally the information into your existing handles/resources.

In my opinion this is a bit misleading. I will create a bug/documentation report to the php as I can't find anything about it. I just stumbled upon as I checked how guzzle did the low-level implementation of it.

```
// your code...

do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    curl_multi_select($mh);
} while ($running > 0);

while ($result = curl_multi_info_read($mh)) {}

foreach($ch as $handle) {
    echo "Handle: " . curl_errno($handle) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: i used your suggestion.
Success: 0 Success: 0 Success: 0 Success: 0 Success: 0 Success: 0
thats the result i get. it doesnt give an error instead returns a 0 as status code.

Comment: @Faaeq, apologies. My first answer was totally wrong (I did only test the success case). It seems that curl_multi() behaves differently and does not pass the error to it's handles but there is a different way through `curl_multi_info_read()` which will return a `curl_errno()`. Please let me know if it will help you now.

Comment: thanks for the response. i used your suggestion. did a vardump before passing the urls and im getting these results even though i'm connected to internet. and those links are up and running.
```
C:\wamp64\www\test3.php:11:
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'http://google.com' (length=17)
  1 => string 'http://bbc.com' (length=14)
  2 => string 'http://yahoo.com/nonexistinglink' (length=32)
Error: Couldn't resolve host name Error: Couldn't resolve host name Error: Couldn't resolve host name
```

Comment: Can you try to add the protocol? `http://` or `https://` to the URLs?

Comment: the links have http:// in the begining. it doesnt show here when i paste it for some reason. i just did a test with https:// too. still the same result.

Comment: Interessting. Can you try to set `CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT` to 0 to enforce a new DNS lookup? Maybe it's cached? I guess a regular `ping google.com` does work?

Comment: I found the problem, it was becuase i'm behind a proxy, so adding `curl_setopt($ch[$key],CURLOPT_PROXY, '192.168.43.1:7000');` solved that. but i just get the result for the first url and nothing for the rest of the urls.

Comment: @Faaeq can you add your latest version of your code example to your question?